# Alternar estado (True/False) ao clicar em um botão - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite!

Estou testando e aprendendo JS, e houve uma dúvida que até o momento não consegui resolver. Tenho uma página simples em HTML, onde a ideia é que que cada vez que eu clicar em um botão, quero que ele fique com um efeito, e se eu clicar novamente, ele retire o efeito (e assim sucessivamente, sempre alternando o estado ao click).

Consigo fazer ele ficar com o efeito ao clicar no botão, mas não consigo fazer ele retirar o efeito quando clico novamente.

Já testei algumas formas e lógicas, mas não consigo fazer. A ideia que tive foi verificar o "estado" do botão, se for TRUE, ele troca a cor, caso contrário ele irá tirar a cor, mas a minha validação sempre cai para TRUE.

Acredito que o problema esteja na função pegaEstado(), pois ela sempre pega a variável estado como nula, fazendo ela sempre enviar TRUE, mas não sei como eu poderia "gravar" a última informação da variável, tentei colocar para ela receber uma função que guardaria o estado, mas sem sucesso. Gostaria de ideias para resolver essa lógica. (segue abaixo o código compilando)

```js
var button_MudaCor = document.querySelector("#mudarCor");

button_MudaCor.onclick = function mudaEstado() {
 if (pegaEstado() == true) {
  mudaCor(true);
 } else {
  mudaCor(false);
 }
};

function pegaEstado() {
 var estado = guardaEstado();

 if (estado == null || estado == true) {
  guardaEstado(true);
  estado = true;
 } else {
  guardaEstado(false);
  estado = false;
 }
 return estado;
};

function guardaEstado(teste) {
 this.teste = teste;
};

function mudaCor(state) {
 if (state == true) {
  button_MudaCor.className = "changeColor";
 } else {
  button_MudaCor.className = "";
 }
};
```

```css
.changeColor {
 border-style: outset;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 box-shadow: 3px -3px 8px 1px  grey ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style_index.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter|Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <header></header>

 <main>
  <section class="login">
   <h2>Faça o login ou cadastra-se</h2>
   <div>
    <input type="text" id="usuario" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Usuário ou e-mail">
    <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
    <button class="botao" id="logar">Login</button>
    <button class="botao" target="_self" id="cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
    <button class="botao" id="mudarCor">Mudar cores</button>
   </div>
  </section>
 </main>
 <footer></footer>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Model/model.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Controller/controller.js" aynsc></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara, tem muita coisa desnecessária no seu código para o objetivo de apenas mudar uma cor.
O que realmente você quer aprender com esse código?

Comment: @FranckCosta, a ideia na verdade era criar uma lógica mais "pura" para o objetivo, sem utilizar recursos do próprio JS/ES6, e sim usando apenas condicionais e repetições.

Comment: Entendo, dei uma resposta adaptando seu código, mas o que o @fwerther fez é o jeito mais simples e correto de se fazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara, como o @fwerther mencionou, algo para apenas a mudança de classe e o que ele fez supri suas necessidades.
No entanto, adaptei seu código fazer mais sentido, se você quer ter a dinâmica de guardar o estado para algum tipo de processamento depois, você tem que muda-lo assim que receber a informação, por exemplo, se você recebe ele como `true` então você precisa guarda-lo como `false`, para posteriormente consegui fazer as mudanças. No que você fez ele sempre guarda o estado como `true`, assim nunca haverá alteração.

```
var stateClass = true;
var button_MudaCor = document.querySelector("#mudarCor");

button_MudaCor.onclick = function mudaEstado() {
    if (pegaEstado() == true) {
        mudaCor(true);
        guardaEstado(false);
    } else {
        mudaCor(false);
        guardaEstado(true);
    }
};

function pegaEstado() {
    return stateClass;
};

function guardaEstado(teste) {
    stateClass = teste;
};

function mudaCor(state) {
    if (state == true) {
        button_MudaCor.className.add('changeColor');
    } else {
        button_MudaCor.classList.remove('changeColor');
    }
};
```

Comment: Show, não tinha pensado nisso. Seria como utilizar um GET e SET?

Comment: Exatamente, GET para pegar o valor e o SET para retornar esse valor, na lógica essas funções servem apenas para isso, sem tomada de decisões.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela ajuda, deu uma boa esclarecida.

Comment: Se você estiver interessado em manter o valor e não apenas em mudar a cor vale a pena ficar ligado na sintaxe ES6 de getters e setters. Você deveria definir os métodos de forma padronizada, get propriedade() e set propriedade(valor). Aí depois de definir assim pode usar direto objeto.propriedade ou objeto.propriedade = valor. Mais informações em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get e https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set e https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax

Answer (score 4):

Achei seu código meio bagunçado, mas, se o objetivo era só trocar as cores, vê se esse exemplo responde seu problema:

```
var button_MudaCor = document.querySelector("#mudarCor");

button_MudaCor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

  if (button_MudaCor.classList.contains('changeColor')) {
    button_MudaCor.classList.remove('changeColor');
  } else {
    button_MudaCor.classList.add('changeColor');
  }

}, false);
```

Você pode ver o exemplo funcionando em https://jsfiddle.net/knvg6h2o/

Comment: Ele resolve o problema (era exatamente isso rsrsrs). É que a ideia em si era fazer o processo sem utilizar muito os recursos do JS/ES6, apenas para treinar lógica (mas realmente, o seu modo é o mais correto).